# Kendo Tooltip not properly closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-tooltip

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h185js61/

```
var tooltip = $("#DIV_ID").kendoTooltip({
    showAfter: 100,
    autoHide: true
});
```

Screenshot of the problem: [image]

Problem:
Kendo Tooltip (API: http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/tooltip) does not properly hide the tooltip even though autohide is set to true.

This happens when I move the mouse over-and-out "Some Content" in my demo very quickly (which users do). I am catching the mouseout event with jquery which works.

Goal: I think this is a Kendo bug! Hence I am looking for a way to destroy the tooptip on jquery's mouseout event which works correctly.

Comment: I can't see any issue with FF. What's your browser?

Comment: FF works:) I am trying it with Chrome

Comment: Internet Explorer (10,11) fails as well. Only FF works

Comment: Adding this to the tooltip works, but it is an ugly hack.            .on('mouseout', function(e){
  $('#'+e.target.id).data('kendoTooltip').hide();
}) ____ http://jsfiddle.net/1Ljy2kzq/

Comment: In Chrome it works as on FF

Comment: @erikscandola: well my screenshot proves otherwise

Comment: Maybe the problem is on Chrome version

Comment: Found another thread with people having a similar problem: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/284

Answer (score 3):

```
var tooltip = $("#DIV_ID").kendoTooltip({
    showAfter: 100,
    autoHide: true
}).on('mouseout', function(e){
  $('#'+e.target.id).data('kendoTooltip').hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1Ljy2kzq/

Adding a mouseout effect with jquery and then force hiding the current tooltip works as a hack.